# make backbone.js 'fetch' auto-update the view

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, fetch

I'm attempting what should be an elementary task with Backbone.js, and can't get it to work.  I just want to perform a *fetch* operation on my model and have it update the view.  Here's my code:

```
(function($) {
    var HomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            lead: "not logged in",
        },
        url: 'test.php'
    });

    var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            this.model = new HomeModel();
            this.model.bind("change", this.render);
            this.model.fetch();
        },

        el: $("#content"),

        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.model.get("lead"));
        }
    });

    var homeView = new HomeView();
})(jQuery);
```

I can see "test.php" loading successfully, but the *render* function never gets called.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you see what "test.php" loaded succesfully? Maybe an AJAX request is succesful, but a response is not a valid JSON? Try to add success and error callbacks to the fetch call: `this.model.fetch({success: function (resp) { console.log('success: %o', resp) }, error: function (er) { console.log('error: %o', er) });`

Comment: I should have known.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think I have the correct answer. You are referring to `this` in your `render` function, but the context of `this` is the event and not your class. You should therefore use underscore's `bindAll` function to bind the class to the function's internals. Like so:

```
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render'); // bind 'this' in 'render'
        this.model = new HomeModel();
        this.model.bind("change", this.render);
        this.model.fetch();
    },
});
```

Otherwise this.el does not exist, or it is wrong at least, and fails quietly.

Comment: It's the same result.  (I've noticed *bind* does still work in other contexts.)

Comment: Hmm sorry about that. Do you have a jsfiddle or something that we can play with?